Is it possible to Approve a ProcessInstanceWorkitem as another user in a Test Class?
I'm trying to approve a ProcessInstanceWorkitem as its ActorId in a test class, but I'm receiving the following error:
System.DmlException: Process failed. First exception on row 0; first error: INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_ON_CROSS_REFERENCE_ENTITY, insufficient access rights on cross-reference id: []
If I log in as the ActorId and approve through the UI, it works.
Code:
@isTest
private static void approve() {

    // logic here to submit record to approval process

    ProcessInstanceWorkitem actorIdWorkItem = [
        SELECT Id, ActorId
        FROM ProcessInstanceWorkitem
        WHERE ActorId = '999999999999999' // Hardcoded ficticious user id to simplify // I am able to log in as the real one and approve the work item without issues.
        LIMIT 1
    ];

    Assert.areNotEqual(null, actorIdWorkItem);

    User actorIdUser = [
        SELECT Id
        FROM User
        WHERE Id = :actorIdWorkItem.ActorId
    ];

    Assert.areNotEqual(null, actorIdUser);

    System.runAs(actorIdUser) {

        Test.startTest();

            Approval.ProcessWorkitemRequest request = new Approval.ProcessWorkitemRequest();
            request.setComments('Approved');
            request.setAction('Approve');
            request.setWorkitemId(actorIdWorkItem.Id);
            Approval.process(request); // error happens here

        Test.stopTest();
    }
}


the 9999999 has to be either an org UserId obtained via SOQL in the testmethod or a est method mocked and inserted User

It HAS to be queried? Cause that 999 in my code is actually the ActorId of a Workitem. What's funny is if the ActorId is admin, then it works... however like I mentioned before, I'm able to approve the request without issues using the UI on non admin users.

it has to be a real UserId - if you're hardcoding it in a testmethod, that is not best practice

Yeah, I'm not hardcoding in my actual code. I just hardcoded it here to simplify the code. I guess I should have just pasted the actual code, but it is kinda big.
